# Highcharts - series order on stacked charts

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create the powerpoint chart below in highcharts however as you can see the order of the series do not match. The legend and the categories match but I'm not sure how to make the series order match?

[image]

This is what my highcharts replica looks like (link to jsfiddle: `(https://jsfiddle.net/6qxukd74/1/`)

[image]

How can I make the highcharts look exactly like the powerpoint chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to the yAxis the reversedStacks property

```
...
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        reversedStacks: false
    },
...
```